# WinAppDriver | executing .bat file

Tags: winappdriver

I am trying to execute .bat file using WinAppDriver. Everything is fine however, there are 2 sessions getting created.

Expected: Chrome browser must launch once and navigate to stackoverflow page only once

**My java code snippet:**

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setDesiredCapabilities() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Executing...");
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\Users\karan\Desktop\chrome.bat");
        SkypeSession = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), desiredCapabilities);
        System.out.println("Is browsert?" +SkypeSession.isBrowser());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My .bat opens chrome browser and navigates to stackoverflow
start "" http://www.stackoverflow.com

Below is error log generated by winAppDriver

```
POST /session HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 143
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_131)

{"capabilities":[{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\Users\karan\Desktop\chrome.bat","platformName":"Windows"}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}]}
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 141
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":100,"value":{"error":"invalid argument","message":"Bad capabilities. Specify either app or appTopLevelWindow to create a session"}}
```

Actual: Chrome browser is launched once however, stackoverflow is launched twice in 2 adjacent tabs.
Please help.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try launching Chrome with Selenium ChromeDriver instead of WinAppDriver and a batch file. Please share the contents of your .bat file here.